# ignore values from react hook returned array -

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

I am using react-cookie, and it's hook looks like this:

```
const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies([
    'cookie-name
  ]);
```

Often I just want to use setCookie, but without getting the actual cookies.

This results in the warning:
`'cookies' is assigned a value but never used`

Is there something I can do to avoid this warning here, preferribly without having to put a comment before the line in each case that I need it?

I tried

```
const [null, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies([
    'cookie-name
  ]);
```

But that doesn't work because it tries to assign the value to null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get only indexes 1 and 2 with array destructuring, do:

```
const [, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies([
  'cookie-name
]);
```